# Loading associated model data in XTemplate

Tags: model, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, associations

I searched a lot the last two days, but couldn't figure out a solution. Here's a description of my problem:

I have a Sencha Touch app with one simple list as view, 2 models (CartItem and Article) and 2 corresponding stores (CartItems and Articles).

The CartItem model has a "hasOne" association to a Article model.

The list view should display all CartItems together with a description of the related article.

Shouldn't be that difficult right? The associations in general do work, i got the article-description via:

```
> Ext.getStore('cartItemStore').getAt(0).getArticle().get('description')
"Example article 1"
```

But I'm not able to get this description displayed in my list.

What I already tried is to use

```
  1) <tpl for="Article">{description}</tpl>
     -> doesn't display anything. Neither data nor an error.
  2) {Article.description}
     in combination with:
     http://appointsolutions.com/2012/07/using-model-associations-in-sencha-touch-2-and-ext-js-4/
     -> f***ed up my whole storage-system :/
```

So any ideas how I can display the associated data in my Template? I would be really thankful if anybody would find a solution! Here's a minimal code example:

**Main.js**

```
Ext.define('assoTempl.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: 'main',
    config: {
        store: 'cartItemStore',
        scrollable: 'vertical',
        itemTpl: '<span>{cart_pos} <tpl for="Article">{description}</tpl></span>'
    }
});
```

**CartItem.js** (CartItem Model)

```
Ext.define('assoTempl.model.CartItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'cart_pos'},
            { name: 'article_id'}
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory'
        },
        hasOne: {
            model: 'assoTempl.model.Article',
            name: 'Article',
            foreignKey: 'ANr',
            foreignStore: 'ArticleStore'
        }
    }
});
```

**Article.js** (Article Model)

```
Ext.define('assoTempl.model.Article', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'ANr', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'description', type: 'String' }
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory'
        }
    }
});
```

**CartItems.js** (CartItem Store)

```
Ext.define("assoTempl.store.CartItems", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.Sql'],
    config: {
        storeId: 'cartItemStore',
        model: "assoTempl.model.CartItem",
        data: [
            {cart_pos:0, article_id:0},
            {cart_pos:1, article_id:1}
        ],
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

**Articles.js** (Article Store)

```
Ext.define("assoTempl.store.Articles", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.Sql'],
    config: {
        storeId: 'articleStore',
        model: "assoTempl.model.Article",
        data: [
            {ANr:0, description:'Example article 1'},
            {ANr:1, description:'I am article 2'}
        ],
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

oh god, sorry for bothering you. Nobody said I've got to execute

`cartItem.setArticle(myArticle);`

before I can access the association. -.-